# How can I fire off a jquery function on an OnSelectedChange?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm creating a dynamic dropdown list on my page. When an option is selected from the dropdown, how can I get it to fire off the jquery function?

Jquery:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                   function insertIntoReporting(_storeID, _personID) {
                      $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/InsertIntoReporting",
                        data: "{'storeID': _storeID, 'personID': _personID}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (msg) {
                        $('').text(msg.d);
                         }
                       });
                      return false;
                   }

                });


            </script>
```

C# Code Behind

```
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "DropdownlistID";
            ddl.Items.Add("----------");
            ddl.DataTextField = "StoreName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "StoreID";
            ddl.DataSource = ds;
            ddl.DataBind();
            e.Item.Cells[4].Controls.Add(ddl);


            [WebMethod]
            public static string InsertIntoReporting(int _storeID, string _personID)
            {
               // database calls go here
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your dropdownlist in a protected field in the code-behind, then:

```
$('<%=_ddl.ClientId%>').change(insertIntoReporting);
```

Another option would be to make your `insertIntoReporting` function more globally accessible, and then do something like this:

```
e.Item.Cells[4].Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
    string.Format(
        @"<script>$(function() {   
            $('{0}').change(insertIntoReporting);
        });</script>",
        ddl.ClientId)));
```

And yet another option (which I'd personally prefer) would be to add some class to all the dropdownlists that you want to have this behavior, and make your javascript block include a line that selects all those by their class:

```
$('.report-insert-dropdown').change(insertIntoReporting);
```

Answer (score 0):

your look for [jQuery's change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

It will look something like this:

```
$('#DropdownlistID').change(insertIntoReporting);
function insertIntoReporting(_storeID, _personID) {
    // $(this) refers to the element that fired the event
    //In this case $(this).val() should be the equivilant as _storeId
    //im not sure where _personId is coming from so I will assume its in an input with id of personId
    var _storeId = $(this).val();
    var _personID = $('#personId').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/InsertIntoReporting",
        data: "{'storeID': _storeID, 'personID': _personID}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('').text(msg.d);
            }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But I have multiple dropdown lists on my page which have multiple IDs. How would I do that?

Comment: add a class to them and target them all that way. so instead of `$('#DropdownlistID').change` it would be `$('.DropDownListItem').change` or whatever class you'd like to assign to the dropdowns. You could also just target the `select tag but this will listen for the event for ALL dropdowns on the page